# No log file when using log4net with XML configuration

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a problem logging to a file when using log4net and my XML configuration in the app.config below. The logfile doesn't appear on the filesystem, so there is probably something wrong, but I can't figure out what it might be.

The code and configuration is shown below.

App.config

```
    </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
        <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="example.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="Console" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>


  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <NetSuiteClient.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="NetSuiteClient_com_netsuite_webservices_NetSuiteService"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2016_1</value>
            </setting>
        </NetSuiteClient.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Declaring:

```
private static readonly ILog _Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Form));
```

Calling:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Log.Info("Info");
    _Log.Debug("Debug");
    _Log.Error("Error");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you instructing Log4Net to look for its configuration in the app.config file? You can do that by using the following assembly-level attribute:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]`

Example taken from [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)